# Mean value of data with varying time step

Tags: vb.net, vba, time

I have a number of dataseries with timestep varying between a few seconds and maybe 120 minutes represented in decimal hours after January 1st. For example one value can be given at time 4692.759994 and the next at 4692.769281. The values can be both positive and negative. I would like to calculate mean values for any given time (usually 1 hour) and wonder of somebody have made anything similar. The code will probable in VBA or VB.net.

Thanks

Comment: you need to figure out 2 things: the interval, and translate at least  one number into date/time. Then you build your algorithm based on what you know.

Answer (score 0):

If you use vb.net you might find this useful:

```
    Dim dtbase As New DateTime(Now.Year, 1, 1)
    Dim t1 As DateTime = dtbase.AddHours(4692.759994)
    Dim t2 As DateTime = dtbase.AddHours(4692.769281)
    Dim Interval As TimeSpan = t2 - t1 'the result is 00:00:33.4340000
```